# asp.net - Specified cast not valid Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I got this error when I am trying the below code

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> projjType = from projT in dtProjList.AsEnumerable()
                                 where projT.Field<int?>("ProjectId") == projId && 
                                 projT.Field<int?>("FilterId") == 1 
                                 select projT;
```

and the stack trace of error is

```
at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.NullableField[TElem](Object value)
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
   at Folder.Projects.<>c__DisplayClass28.<repProjectList_ItemDataBound>b__1e(DataRow projT) in D:\Folder\Project.aspx.cs:line 1061
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

where the dtProjList is DataTable,and Table Structure is as follows,

```
ProjectId (int)
ProjectName (string)
ProjectThumb (string)
FilterTypeId (int)
FilterId (int)
FilterType (string)
```

all are not null values.Can anybody please help me out.

thanks in advance.

**Update** :: This is onlyrecord in my table,is the error because of the single record ??

```
ProjectId   ProjectName ProjectThumb    FilterTypeId    FilterId    FilterType
   1    Datamaster  small_14.jpg         1             1               Final
```

Comment: What is the type (and value) of `projId`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all fields are not null, then cast fields to `int` instead of nullable `int?`

```
var projjType = from projT in dtProjList.AsEnumerable()
                where projT.Field<int>("ProjectId") == projId && 
                      projT.Field<int>("FilterId") == 1 
                select projT;
```

Comment: thank you @lazyberezovsky for quick reply,but I tried this also.Its still not working.

Comment: @gofor.net What is not working? BTW Verify that `projId` variable has type of `int`.

Comment: @gofor.net then all should work. Again, what error do you receive?

Comment: @gofor.net which cast is specified?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19286/discussion-between-gofor-net-and-lazyberezovsky)